# Extract only the root nodes using jsonpath

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

In a nutshell, I am trying to extract only the root nodes from a JSON data using jsonpath with java. In the JSON data below, there are only 2 nodes at the root level, `store` and `expensive`. My aim is to get the names of just those 2 nodes stored in a variable and then go on to create an assertion that said nodes are not empty or null.

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  },
  "expensive": 10
```

This is what I have tried:

```
JsonPath jpath = new JsonPath(json);
Map<String, Object> loc = jpath.get("$");
```

The $ is getting me all the root nodes plus the children. Is there a way to exclude the children and just get the root nodes?

Comment: Try with `"$.*~"`

Comment: @chomnoue Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. Its returning the error:

JSONPath Error: Unable to parse token *~ in expression: .*~.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I got it from https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath, but it looks like the original spec doesn't support it yet

Comment: Isn't "root nodes" somwhat of a contradiction? There is only one root.

Comment: @Henry store and expensive are the outer nodes on the same level; hence, the reason for calling them root. Is it possible to get a list of those 2 outer nodes without any child being extracted?